# Reshape in Fortran90

Tags: arrays, fortran, reshape

I need to reshape a 2D matrix (A) with dimension as 3*8 to matrix (B) with dimension as (6*4) in Fortran as the example below.

```
Matrix A 

1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6
7 8 7 8 7 8 7 8

Matrix B                       
    1 1 1 1
    2 2 2 2
    5 5 5 5
    6 6 6 6
    7 7 7 7
    8 8 8 8
```

I tried as the following with looping but seems to be very slow for large matrices. I was thinking if such reshaping is possible with `RESHAPE` function in Fortran 90.

```
        counter=1
        do i=1,size(A,2),2
            seq1(counter)=i
            counter=1+counter
        end do

        counter=1
        do i=2,size(A,2),2
          seq2(counter)=i
          counter=1+counter
        end do

        counter=1
        do i=1,size(A,1)*2,2
          S_1(counter)=i
          counter=1+counter
        end do

        counter=1
        do i=2,size(A,1)*2,2
          S_2(counter)=i
          counter=1+counter
        end do

        Do i=1,size(A,1)
          B(S_1(i),:)=A(i,seq1)
          B(S_2(i),:)=A(i,seq2)
        END DO
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code does the appropriate reshaping, but you should run your program through a profiler to gauge performance. How aggressive is your optimization flag?

```
  B(1:2,:) = reshape(source=A(1,:), shape=[2,4])
  B(3:4,:) = reshape(source=A(2,:), shape=[2,4])
  B(5:6,:) = reshape(source=A(3,:), shape=[2,4])
```

and to reverse the transformation,

```
  A(1,:) = reshape(source=B(1:2,:), shape=[8])
  A(2,:) = reshape(source=B(3:4,:), shape=[8])
  A(3,:) = reshape(source=B(5:6,:), shape=[8])
```